# Databricks 11 MLflow error "permission denied" in create_tmp_dir

Tags: databricks, mlflow

I'm getting "permission denied" errors when using MLflow 2.1.8 with Databricks runtime 11.3.

It looks like it is trying to write to `/tmp`, which you can't do in Databricks.

I tried setting `MLFLOW_DFS_TMP` in the environment, but this seems not to do anything.

It looks like later versions of Databricks like DBR 13 have support for setting the temporary directory, but I'm stuck on DBR 11 for other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked this down in the MLflow source.

According to [the current source as of 2023-11-30](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/4b8bb73ea5e30e3df312ae4ce9d1d3825a6faf09/mlflow/utils/file_utils.py#L840-843), MLflow is catching all exceptions when looking for the temp directory support on Databricks:

```py
try:
    return _get_dbutils().entry_point.getReplLocalTempDir()
except Exception:
    pass
```

It falls back to using `/tmp` when the method `getReplLocalTempDir` is not found on `entry_point`, throwing an exception.

I monkey-patched the databricks runtime from my notebook:

```py
from mlflow.utils.databricks_utils import _get_dbutils

def fake_tmp():
  return '/dbfs/...' # something writable

_get_dbutils().entry_point.getReplLocalTempDir = fake_tmp
```

This allows `mlflow.pyfunc.log_model()` to run in the old Databricks runtime. It's not necessary for DBR 13, but I had to run on DBR 11 for reasons.